# Avoid fungus on top soil (indoor plant)

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, watering, soil, fungus

I’m growing some sweet potato vines inside my house out of a well-draining tin pot. Where the vines cluster together, naturally less sunlight reaches the top soil and I’ve got little white mould spots starting to grow.

The potato requires regular watering and I don’t have a fungicide on hand, so today I mixed some apple cider vinegar with camomile tea (not sure what the tea does but it’s an online recipe) and poured that on top. By the end of the day, the mould was still there so I dusted some cinnamon on top (another online suggestion) until I can figure out what the best solution is.

Should I be mixing anything in the daily plant water to keep fungus away? I’m in S England and we’re entering the cold wet months so I assume if I don’t figure out how to control it now it will only get worse in the near future.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: We are entering in "cold wet weather", but you say it is an indoor plant, right? Which soil do you used?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi That’s correct but my flat gets damp in the winter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually read the 1 star reviews on the soil I purchased and looks like everyone had mould problems (some even bugs in their new bags)... looks like it’s best to re-pot with a different brand and as someone suggested, water less frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Potatoes requires watering, but not too much watering.

I think you should reduce watering. If you have fungus, probably you water too much. I never have problem with irregular (and seldom) watering of potatoes, so I'm surprised to your comment.

As alternatives: a watering system, where you water soil and not the surface helps. Or a top layer of sand helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I water my potato plant once a week with half a cup of water-- how does that compare to your "seldom watering"? Am I still watering too much?